# PDF.js giving CORS issue in first attempt but after doing hard refresh its working fine without any issue

Tags: python, django

PDF.js giving CORS issue in first attempt but after doing hard refresh its working fine without any issue.

[image]

```js
    url = localStorage.getItem('pdf_url')
    var pdfDoc = pdfjsLib.getDocument(
        {url:localStorage.getItem('pdf_url'),
        crossDomain: true, 
        cache: false,
        mode:'no-cors',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*',
        ' Access-Control-Allow-Methods':"POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT", 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET', 
        httpHeaders: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}}
        ).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
        displayPage(pdf, 1);

    shownPdf = pdf;
    __PDF_DOC = pdf;
   __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;
   $('.total').text(__TOTAL_PAGES)
```

Comment: It is due to caching, may be cache=false can slove this problem

Comment: @harshitverma tried that also but still same issue